# Convert a String representation of Object back to an Object of original type in java

Tags: java

I am using  type conversion given below in my project.

**

```
ArrayList<Object> arr=new ArrayList<Object>();
String str=arr.toString();
```

**

I want to convert field ***str*** back into `ArrayList<Object>` type.

How to go through?

thanks for Help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert String into a Class Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401467/convert-string-into-a-class-object)

Comment: Using `toString()` doesn't tantamount to *type conversion* but merely a textual representation of your original object, in this case, `arr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ought to be using the `Serializable` interface, `ObjectOutputStream`  / `ObjectInputStream` and byte[] to String conversion such as `DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary` / `DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary`

Answer (score 1):

`toString()` is a protocol. It is defined to produce some string or another. It is *not* defined to produce a string reversible to an object. Many classes `toString` methods are designed to produce *human readable* results, which are nearly guaranteed to *not* be reversible.

The Java technology universe contains a number of mechanisms for serializing objects into bytes that can be stored or transmitted and then deserialized into objects. These include the built-in Java Object Streams, the build-in Java JAX-B XML marshal/unmarshaling technologies, and then open-source alternatives just as Jackson for mapping to and from Json or Yaml, and many others.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this, is to Override the `toString()` method of the Object in your ArrayList. Say your object has 2 attributes: `int size` and `String name`. Your constructor would possible be

```
public YourObject(int size, String name){
    this.size = size;
    this.name = name;
}
```

Now you override your object:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return Integer.toString(this.size) + "#" + this.name;
}
```

In order to create the object again, you will also need another constructor or setter:

```
public YourObject(String attributes){
    String[] parts = attributes.split("#");
    this.size = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
    this.name = parts[1];
}
```

To go from object to string and back:

```
List<YourObject> arr; //Initialise this array
List<String> arrStrings = new ArrayList<String>();

//Convert to list of strings
for (YourObject yourObject : arr){
    arrStrings.add(yourObject.toString());
}

//Convert it back
List<YourObject> yourObjects = new ArrayList<YourObject>();
for (String converted : arrStrings){
    yourObjects.add(new YourObject(converted));
}
```

If you wish to use a native object, create your own object and extend the native.

Other than that, there is no way to do what you want. And note that this is **very** prone to error! So be sure to check for length of strings, sizes of arrays and whatnot.