# how to convert a String to Object in JAVA

Tags: java, string, object

I am retrieving a `String` variable from the `Database` and storing in a variable.

```
String name = "Peter"     ---- >(retrieved from the database)
```

I already have a class called `Peter`.  I need to initialize the class using the retrieved variable `name`.

Assume that ,whatever `String` is retrieved from the database , I have a class defined for it in my package...

Is there a way to create a `Object` for the `String` I retrieve from the `Database`?

Comment: If your Peter string is coming in a json format the you can deserialize that and "convert" it into an Peter Object

Comment: Peter is just coming from a SQL table . it is just comes out as a String .( by doing a sql select call)

Comment: @Gowtham Shankar : You should add code snippet here

Comment: How does Peter look like? ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert String into a Class Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401467/convert-string-into-a-class-object)

Comment: I think you need this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268817/create-new-class-from-a-variable-in-java

Comment: Class Peter {

}


Class MainProg {

String a = session.get(table,key);
// a contains peter.....



}

I need to create Class for whatever data is stored in String a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Class.forName()` - java.lang.reflect
If we know the name of the class & if it has a public default constructor we can create an object in this way.

```
Class myClass = Class.forName("MyClass");

Class[] types = {Double.TYPE, this.getClass()};
Constructor constructor = myClass.getConstructor(types);

Object[] parameters = {new Double(0), this};
Object instanceOfMyClass = constructor.newInstance(parameters);
```

See [Java how to instantiate a class from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495785/java-how-to-instantiate-a-class-from-string#7495850)

Comment: What if we don't know the class name ? That's my scenario

Answer (score 6):

```
Class.forName(name).newInstance()
```

Comment: You can comment it also.