# Save Object reference as hex number in Java?

Tags: java, memory, reference

I'm interested in storing the Object reference of the class as an hex number.
I'm able to store as String only.

```
public class Name{
  static void main(String [] args){
    Name name = new Name();
    String ref=name.toString();
    System.out.println(ref);
  }
}
```

The result in this case will be Name@HEXVALUE, and I could get the value splitting the string and parsing. Is this the correct and full reference for this object (Name is just an info of JVM?)?

How could I save as hex value?

Comment: The hex value in `Name@hexvalue` is just the hash code. It is not necessarily a "correct and full reference for this object".

Comment: `String.format("%x", ref.hashCode())`.

Comment: Note that "splitting and parsing" will break if `Name` were to override `toString()`.

Comment: possible similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401467/convert-string-into-a-class-object

Comment: Are you interested in this: `Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(new Object()))`?

Comment: So, to combine two contributions, `String.format("%x", System.identityHashCode(name))` might be the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this reliably and shouldn't try.

**Why you can't:**
Methods like `toString()` or `hashCode()` are not (and have never been) intended to provide this information. They can be overriden (to provide different information, more useful for their intended purpose), and it wouldn't even be outrageous that their default implementation for the `Object` class changes in newer versions of the Java language. So none of the ideas presented is reliable.

**Why you shouldn't try:**
The same program running twice may well get two different hex values for the same variable, so you should never try to store this info on disk, or on any medium that it lasts more than the process itself. I mean, once the process dies the info is useless.

If the idea is to "store" the information in a variable in the current process, it's already stored in the reference variable itself (`name` in your example). You can compare two references with `==` and there is really nothing else anyone could *wish* to do with a reference (at least nothing I can think of).

Which leads me to the question: What is the reason for doing this?