# I am converting a map to string using toString() method. Is there a way I can convert the string back to map?

Tags: java, string, hashmap, maps

```
Map<String,Object> inputMap=new HashMap<String,Object>();

    inputMap.put("a","abc");
    inputMap.put("b","bcd");
    inputMap.put("c","cde");

 HashMap<String,String> subMap=new HashMap<String,String>();
   subMap.put("x","xyz");
    subMap.put("z","klm")

    inputMap.put("d",subMap);




String output=inputMap.toString();
System.out.println(output);


{a=abc,b=bcd,c=cde,d={x=xyz,z=klm}}
```

**the output is : {a=abc,b=bcd,c=cde,d={x=xyz,z=klm}}**;

**How can I convert output back to Map** ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string representing key-value pairs to Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768171/convert-string-representing-key-value-pairs-to-map)

Comment: Try to use clear() method. It Removes all key/value pairs from the invoking map.

Comment: Here is one solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17278809/1270000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can convert the string back to map?

In general, No.

1. The `Map<K,V>.toString()` implementations rely on the `K.toString()` and `V.toString()` implementations.  These are not reversible, which means that the `Map` implementation cannot be either.
2. Even in the `Map<String,String>` case, the rendered map doesn't use any form of escaping to deal with edge-cases ... like keys or values that contain comma, equals or curly brackets.

In restricted cases<sup>1</sup>, you could implement your own parser, or you could use one of the approaches described here:

- [String to HashMap JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514473/string-to-hashmap-java) <sup>2</sup>

However, it is a BAD IDEA to use `toString()` if you also need the transformation to be reversible.  The `toString()` method contract, and its implementation, are not designed for that purpose.  They are primarily designed for use in debug.

---

<sup>1 - For example, if you can assume that `K` and `V` are `String`, there are no `null` keys or values, and neither will contain awkward characters.</sup>

<sup>2 - Beware: simple solutions using `split` etcetera often don't cope with nested maps.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

There is no predefined Java method But You can code with your own logic.
Here I am sharing my work example. **You can change your code as required**

```
  String output="{a=abc,b=bcd,c=cde,d={x=xyz,z=klm}}";
    if(output.indexOf("{")==0 && output.lastIndexOf("}")==output.length()-1) {
            output=output.substring(1, output.length()-1);
        HashMap<String, String> convertedMap=convert(output);
        for (HashMap.Entry<String, String> value:convertedMap.entrySet()) {
            if(value.getValue().indexOf("{")==0 && value.getValue().lastIndexOf("}")==value.getValue().length()-1) {
               String valueWithBracket=value.getValue();
               convertedMap.remove(value);
               convertedMap=convert(valueWithBracket);
            }
        }
    }

  public static HashMap<String, String> convert(String str) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String[] tokens = str.split(",(?![^{)]*\\})");
    for (String token: tokens) {
       String[] val=token.split("=(?![^{)]*\\})");
        for (int i=0;i<val.length;i=i+2) {
            map.put(val[i], val[i+1]);
        }
    }
        return map;
}
public static HashMap<String, String> removeBracketAndConvert(String str){
    if(str.indexOf("{")==0 && str.lastIndexOf("}")==str.length()-1) {
        str=str.substring(1, str.length()-1);
        return convert(str);
    }
    return convert(str);
}
```